# Best practice lookup-tables (GetOrCreate)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

First I want to explain my situation in a few sentences:
- I have a number of, what I call them, lookup-tables. This means I want all values in there to be unique. For example a lookup-table for CPU models with a name and a GUID.

```
public partial class CPUModel : EntityObject
{
    public Guid Id {}
    public String Name{}
}
```

- The entities are safed in a SQL CE database with the help of Entity Framework and C#
- I have made a CRUDManager which helps me to Select, Insert, Update and Delete Entities.
- All these Operations work with a ReaderWriterLockSlim to secure against problems with multithreading.

Now there should be some sort of GetOrCreate Method where I can say GetOrCreate(cpuModelName) and this gives me a saved CPUModel, either already existing or new created. This method should also work with the ReaderWriterLockSlim.

So I would want to implement this method on CRUDManager.
Do you think I'm on the right track or would you place this directly on the CPUModel (or even somewhere else?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

CRUDManager is a good place for it. I would just look the value up (ideally via a `Lookup()` type function, and if it exists, select it. If not, call `Create()` or whatever function you have defined to create it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a dictionary. I recommend reading about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).